# Sails.js iisnode configuration

Tags: node.js, sails.js, iisnode

I'm wondering if anyone could help with getting a sails JavaScript app running in IIS 7 on Windows.

https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/298 did not prove to be helpful for me.

I have gone through the [iisnode setup](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) and created this as my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Tell IIS to use the iisnode module to run your
         application -->
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <!-- Add iisnode with the @nodeProcessCommand line if
     you see the error: Make sure the node.exe executable
     is available at the location specified in the
     system.webServer/iisnode/@nodeProcessCommandLine element
     of web.config. -->
    <iisnode
       nodeProcessCommandLine="%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\node.exe"
    />
    <!-- Since behind the covers, Sails.js is just an express app
    rewrite all urls to processed by iisnode via app.js. This
    will sort out things like the routing to your public
    resources (images, js, styles) and all configured rest
    endpoints. -->
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="root">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Sails is installed and when I run the server from the terminal `sails lift` I can access the app at http://localhost:1337/, but when I attempt to access it through the IIS port8090 I receive a HTTP 500 with the message:

> To run an app using `node app.js`, you usually need to have a version of `sails` installed in the same directory as your app.
>   To do that, run `npm install sails`
>
> Alternatively, if you have sails installed globally (i.e. you did `npm install -g sails`), you can use `sails lift`.
>   When you run `sails lift`, your app will still use a local `./node_modules/sails` dependency if it exists,
>   but if it doesn't, the app will run with the global sails instead!

[image]

Comment: Posting comment on behalf of [Anti21](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5656467/anti21); _Were you able to solve it? Facing same issue. As I have low reputation I am unable to comment._

Comment: I decided not to use iisnode after all. Went with a separate sails app and have an IIS site with an inbound rewrite rule to the sails app. NodeSSPI for windows authentication.